# Starcraft 2 chat name

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

In Starcraft 2 in the Player Profile there are two names.  The first is my alias, what I appear to be during chat in games/loading screens etc.

The second is my real name which shows under the alias.  However this appears to show up in Starcraft 2 chat channels, which I don't really want, I would prefer it show the alias.

Can I either get the chat channels to show my alias, or change wherever the "real-name" is stored to something else?  I poked around the battle.net account web page but didn't see anything promising.

ANSWER: [Only your RealID friends see your real name](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/1991949175?page=1#4)

Comment: Are you sure the chat is displaying your real name to other people in the channel? You real name should only be shown to Real ID friends.

Comment: @Raven - I don't know this for sure, just what it is showing me

Comment: Raven is right, it only shows your real name to those who are your Real ID friends, and only your username to everyone else.

Comment: Posted as answer, below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure the chat is displaying your real name to other people in the channel? You real name should only be shown to Real ID friends.

I bet that you're not actually giving anything other than your alias.

Comment: This is correct. Nothing but your alias shows to non Read ID friends.

Comment: Correct indeed thanks.  I've added a link to my question with a blizzard response in the forum.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how do what you want, but I know WHO KNOWS:

**Write to support:**

http://us.blizzard.com/support/index.xml?locale=en_US

https://us.blizzard.com/support/webform.xml?locale=en_US&selection=StarcraftII => Account Issues => Account Profile.

I have written to them also (sometime in the night), they replayed very quickly next business day, till afternoon.